# ResourceExhaustedError With CNN

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to complete [this tutorial](http://androidkt.com/feeding-your-own-data-set-into-the-cnn-model-in-tensorflow/) with this [source code](http://github.com/Thumar/cnn_dog_vs_cat)

I have tried using their large images data as well as my own small data set of 52 images (46x46) but I keep running into ResourceExhaustedError

```
   ResourceExhaustedError  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1016064,1024]
```

Is there any way I can edit this code so it trains on smaller training sets so I dont run into this error?

I have tried changing batch sizes in the code but this accomplished nothing. I also made sure I dont have any previous tensorflow projects running (i restarted my computer)

my label.txt contains these two lines:

```
cat
dog
```

and my train and validation folders contain 2 subfolders with the same name that contain the images.

---

I am using:
GeForce GTX 850M major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.9015

totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.35GiB

---

before I hit the error I get this print out:

```
Limit:                  3235767910
InUse:                      223232
MaxInUse:                   223232
NumAllocs:                      17
MaxAllocSize:               204800
```

Here is my full error:

```
    2018-07-01 14:55:45.724585: W C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:279] *___________________________________________________________________________________________________
2018-07-01 14:55:45.725147: W C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1202] OP_REQUIRES failed at random_op.cc:202 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1016064,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1361, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1340, in _run_fn
    target_list, status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1016064,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[Node: dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform = RandomUniform[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@dense/kernel"], dtype=DT_FLOAT, seed=0, seed2=0, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mac/Desktop/tensorflow/cnn_dog_vs_cat-master/cnn_dog_cat.py", line 175, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:/Users/Mac/Desktop/tensorflow/cnn_dog_vs_cat-master/cnn_dog_cat.py", line 167, in main
    classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(train_list), steps=10, hooks=[logging_hook])
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 352, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 888, in _train_model
    log_step_count_steps=self._config.log_step_count_steps) as mon_sess:
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 384, in MonitoredTrainingSession
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 795, in __init__
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 518, in __init__
    self._sess = _RecoverableSession(self._coordinated_creator)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 981, in __init__
    _WrappedSession.__init__(self, self._create_session())
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 986, in _create_session
    return self._sess_creator.create_session()
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 675, in create_session
    self.tf_sess = self._session_creator.create_session()
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 446, in create_session
    init_fn=self._scaffold.init_fn)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\session_manager.py", line 281, in prepare_session
    sess.run(init_op, feed_dict=init_feed_dict)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1137, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1355, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1374, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1016064,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[Node: dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform = RandomUniform[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@dense/kernel"], dtype=DT_FLOAT, seed=0, seed2=0, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.


Caused by op 'dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform', defined at:
  File "C:/Users/Mac/Desktop/tensorflow/cnn_dog_vs_cat-master/cnn_dog_cat.py", line 175, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:/Users/Mac/Desktop/tensorflow/cnn_dog_vs_cat-master/cnn_dog_cat.py", line 167, in main
    classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(train_list), steps=10, hooks=[logging_hook])
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 352, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 812, in _train_model
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 793, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Mac/Desktop/tensorflow/cnn_dog_vs_cat-master/cnn_dog_cat.py", line 50, in cnn_model_fn
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\core.py", line 248, in dense
    return layer.apply(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py", line 809, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py", line 680, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\core.py", line 134, in build
    trainable=True)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py", line 533, in add_variable
    partitioner=partitioner)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 1297, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 1093, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 439, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 408, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource, constraint=constraint)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 800, in _get_single_variable
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 2157, in variable
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 2147, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 2130, in default_variable_creator
    constraint=constraint)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 233, in __init__
    constraint=constraint)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 327, in _init_from_args
    initial_value(), name="initial_value", dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 784, in <lambda>
    shape.as_list(), dtype=dtype, partition_info=partition_info)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\init_ops.py", line 472, in __call__
    shape, -limit, limit, dtype, seed=self.seed)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\random_ops.py", line 244, in random_uniform
    shape, dtype, seed=seed1, seed2=seed2)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_random_ops.py", line 473, in _random_uniform
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3271, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1016064,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[Node: dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform = RandomUniform[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@dense/kernel"], dtype=DT_FLOAT, seed=0, seed2=0, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

Comment: If this code is hard to fix I would also accept a link to a code that could work on my machine. I just want to get a cnn working on my own dataset

Comment: Would you share your source code? The exhaustion happens on a rather large matrix (assuming you are on simple trial, the numbers look big): [1016064, 1024]. There may be a problem in the code, without formal syntax error. If you are sure that everything’s fine, have you tried a batch of size 1 ? The matrix only seems to take up roughly 1Gb in its current shape (really rough, it depends on the data type...).

Comment: @EricPlaton My source code is identical to tutorial source code with the exception of directory names. I did tried to change all the batch sizes to 1. In this line and in the same code couple lines below " return input_fn(True, file_path, 100, None, 10)" -> return input_fn(True, file_path, 1, None, 10)

Comment: @EricPlaton I guess they make you scroll all the way down in tutorial to dl source code. So here it is https://github.com/Thumar/cnn_dog_vs_cat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OOM is caused by the allocation of the dense layer line 50 :

```
pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 126 * 126 * 64])
dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

You can either:

- reduce the number of neurons in your layer (e.g. from 1024 to 64)
- reduce the dimension of your input image
- increase the downsampling factor of your feature extractor (here since you only have 2 max poooling layers with stride 2, the downsampling factor is 4)

BTW I strongly recommend against using hard coded shapes in tf.reshape. Maybe use tf.layers.flatten which is robust to architecture modifications instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I have reduced the image size  to 46 by 46 I am guessing that it is still too big for my gpu? And btw this isnt my code. This is the only tutorial that i could find that allows me to use CNN on my own images. If you have any other tutorials you could recommend I would greatly appreciate it. I will mark the answer when I fix my code

Comment: I would not recommend this tutorial at all. It didn't see the first time I read the code but there is quite a huge mistake: tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 126 * 126 * 64]) should be tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 62 * 62 * 64]) and in your case with a 46x46 image tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 11 * 11 * 64]).
Please use tf.layers.flatten(pool2) instead.

Comment: As of good computer vision tutorials, the official Tensorflow documentation is quite good and will give you nice examples to modify for your own needs.

Comment: Yes I did change that piece of the code to tf.layers.flatten! And it works now with your other suggestions but I had to use smaller images and 64 units on my dense layer. I guess i cant expect much from a laptop GPU. I hate this tutorial but I couldnt find a better one that explained how to use my own images. I did the Tensorflow official tutorial but I couldnt load anything but minst dataset into it. (i guess ill look around their website a bit more)